# Why does INFO get logged in DEBUG logs

Tags: python, logging, yaml

I am using yaml to config logging for my Python application.

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

formatters:
    standard:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: standard
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO
        formatter: standard
        filename: info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

    error_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR
        formatter: standard
        filename: errors.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

    debug_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: standard
        filename: debug.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 20
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
        db_ops:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: [info_file_handler, error_file_handler, debug_file_handler]
        propagate: true
```

In module `db_ops`, I use both `logger.info` and `logger.debug` for different levels of logging. When I run the app, while `INFO` did get output to info.log, both `INFO` and `DEBUG` messages are output to debug.log.

What is the right way to separate the log to different files based on the level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The levels of python loggers and handlers are thresholds. If you specify your level as DEBUG, it means that **anything equal or above DEBUG** will be logged.

If you want to have a DEBUG logging only, you'll have to additionally assign a filter that will filter anything but DEBUG message.

Comment: so would it be better to have all level output to the same file. that way you don't get redundant logs in different files?

Comment: It really depends on how you utilize logging. It is a common pattern to have DEBUG level enabled for local development but have INFO or above set in production to reduce the noise levels and have important logs only (usually problems).

However, in other cases, your logging needs might be different. For example, you might want errors to go to stderr and regular output to stdout. There are no hard rules about it. 

In your case it sounds like you might get fine just by logging everything to the same destination.