# Odoo logs - how to keep DEBUG, but remove INFO?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, odoo

In odoo, how to disable only the **INFO** log level, but at the same time keep **DEBUG**?
Or do you just have to go through each module in **conf** and disable it's **INFO** logs?

I know about the log levels, but **debug** has lower hierarchy than **info** for some reason.

Related: [Why does INFO get logged in DEBUG logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405336/why-does-info-get-logged-in-debug-logs)

Comment: AFAIK Odoo uses python's logging lib and has no option to do what you want. So maybe a python crack can give a hint about this topic. But very interesting question.